# Desktop resets to single screen when I turn second screen off

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor set-up, and have had this for as long as I can remember.

Right now, I have 1 screen on HDMI and another on DVI.

The problem is that whenever I turn off my HDMI screen, windows does the "hardware ejected" sound and then it actually **switches back to a single screen setup**

This messes up the placement of all my permanently open applications and causes some full-screen applications to crash. I haven't had this issue in quite some time (I have had it once before) and I have no clue how to fix it anymore.

I've noticed that this started happening right after the last big windows update.

Basically, I want windows to completely ignore my turning one of my screens on or off.

Does anybody have a clue?

Thank you.

Important specs:
OS: Windows 10 pro
Graphics card: AMD R9 290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix (for me) was to switch around my HDMI and DVI. As in, take the cables from each screen and hook it up to the other.

Why? I have no idea. But it works. Hope this helps someone